# How to align contents to the centre of html page

Tags: html, css, styles

I have the following html code

```html
<body>
  <h3>Title 1</h3>
  <h3>Title 2</h3>
  <div>
    <a href="ref1">
      <button type="button">Button 1</button>
    </a>
    <span> abcd </span>
    <a href="ref2">
      <button type="button">Button 2</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>value2</td>
        <td>value3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would like to add css to the following to centre align to the page in the following format

```
                      title 1
                      title 2
              button1  abcd  button2
          +----------------------------+
          |   col1 |   col2  |  col3   |
          +----------------------------+
          |   val1 |   val2  |  val3   |
          +----------------------------+
```

The table and titles should be at the centre of page. And the 2 buttons with the snap should
be in the same line with centre aligned. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following style to body tag
display:flex;
justify-content:center;

Answer (score 0):

Add the following styling to the body tag at the top of the html.

`<body style="text-align: center; display: grid; justify-content:center;">`

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <body>
        <center>
          <h3>Title 1</h3>
          <h3>Title 2</h3>
          <div >
            <a href="ref1">
              <button type="button" >Button 1</button>
            </a>
            <span> abcd </span>
            <a href="ref2">
               <button type="button" >Button 2</button>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div >
             <table >
                <tr>
                   <th>Col1</th>
                   <th>Col2</th>
                   <th>Col3</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>value1</td>
                   <td>value2</td>
                   <td>value3</td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </div>
         </center>
        </body>
```

Using HTML `center` tag to align your whole content of your body to center.

Answer (score -1):

use CSS GRID for that
And why you're using table for that?